# Filter By Literal Column Name

Tags: powershell

Using a command against my local IIS of `gci "IIS:\Sites\My Website"` it gets an output where there is a column named `Type`:

[image]

But I am unable to filter *by* that column such as

`| Where-Object {$_.Type -eq 'application'}`

because `Type` is a keyword(?) maybe.

How does one tell the filter to use the literal column name?

---

Original output generated from the `gci` command in the `Webadministration` module:

```
Import-Module Webadministration

gci "IIS:\Sites\My Website"
```

*Note that the actual name of the IIS website has to go into "My Website"* shown above.

Full command that doesn't not filter out the `directory` rows of data and only keeps `application`:

`gci "IIS:\Sites\My Website" | Where-Object {$_.Type -eq 'application'}`

Comment: `Type` is not a keyword in PowerShell. How was the output generated in the first place?

Comment: See update provided.

Comment: I don't have any "type" column at all using a gci statement like yours.

Comment: Try `| Where-Object {$_.NodeType -eq 'application'}`

Comment: @T-Me Ausgezeichnet; that works. Create an answer and I will mark it as such. thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit: 
The Type property can be found with `$_.nodetype`.
So the rest of this Answer is not needed

---

Create your own column name. This way you are able to filter objects by the new one:

```
| Select-Object YourDesiredColumns,@{Name='NewColumn';Expression={$_.Type}}
```

Could be like this:

```
gci "IIS:\Sites\My Website" | Select-Object *,@{Name='Bob';Expression={$_.NodeType}} | Where-Object {$_.Bob -eq 'application'} | ft
```

Comment: I want all the columns.  Its unclear, at this time to me, what this operation actually does....

Comment: you create an extra column called what you want. Now you can filter by that column

Answer (score 1):

Simulating with data from a here string and ConvertFrom-Csv that's doesn't impose a problem:

```
$Data = @"
Type,Application
application,ArchiveServices
directory,aspnet_client
"@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

$Data | Where-Object {$_.Type -eq 'application'}
$Data | Where-Object Type -eq 'application'
```

Comment: I use `{$_.Type -eq 'application'}` and nothing comes out for my processing needs. But if I try your example it works.....but I am not using your data as an example... :-/