# Get customized distribution list report in Exchange By Power-Shell

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I am trying to obtain a report of distribution lists in a particular OU. The result should show the following Columns:

```
 DL name, OU, AcceptMessagesOnlyFromSendersOrMembers, ManagedBy, Count
```

NOTE: I need to get the `AcceptMessagesOnlyFromSendersOrMembers` result by the user displayname and not by canonical name and no need to use the AD module in above method.

I have tried the following code:

```
Get-DistributionGroup -OrganizationalUnit "OU name" -ResultSize Unlimited | select AcceptMessagesOnlyFromSendersOrMembers | Export-Csv C:\Temp\TEST.csv
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: What did you try so far? What results did you get instead? Show us some of the code...

Comment: I have tried below code: 
    Get-DistributionGroup -OrganizationalUnit "OU name" -ResultSize Unlimited  | select  AcceptMessagesOnlyFromSendersOrMembers | Export-Csv C:\Temp\TEST.csv

Comment: anybody can help me?

Comment: I have currently no system to test it on but try this:`Get-DistributionGroup -OrganizationalUnit "OU name" -ResultSize Unlimited | select *` see the properties you need and replace the `*` with the properties separated with commas. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54024087/filter-by-literal-column-name/54024445#54024445) to build your own column.